# Clarity clr-wizard have disable button not working

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I am using `clr-wizard` from clarity design framework for angular 6 projects.

I have 2 step in clr-wizard like below code.

```
<clr-wizard>
    <clr-wizard-page [clrWizardPageNextDisabled]="!stepFirstNextButtonEnable">
        <ng-template clrPageTitle>Platforms</ng-template>
        <ng-container>
            ....
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template clrPageButtons>
            <clr-wizard-button class="custom-btn-primary" [type]="'custom-next-step-first'">NEXT</clr-wizard-button>
        </ng-template>
    </clr-wizard-page>

    <clr-wizard-page [clrWizardPageNextDisabled]="!stepSecondNextButtonEnable">
        <ng-template clrPageTitle>Platforms</ng-template>
        <ng-container>
            ....
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template clrPageButtons>
            <clr-wizard-button class="custom-btn-primary" [type]="'custom-next-step-second'">NEXT</clr-wizard-button>
        </ng-template>
    </clr-wizard-page>
</clr-wizard>
```

I have to use custom `NEXT` button in each step so I am using `<ng-template clrPageButtons></ng-template>` and I am using `[clrWizardPageNextDisabled]` for making button disable in each step.

In first step button disable is working before some days. Now that is not working.

If we remove the custom button `<ng-template clrPageButtons>`

Reference:

https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.13/wizards

Comment: Can you please put your code into a functional Stackblitz to show the whole implementation? This can help you get started https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v013

Comment: Please check the demo. The same issue occurred. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clr-wizard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `type` of your custom button should be `next` or `custom-next`:

```
<clr-wizard-button type="custom-next">NEXT</clr-wizard-button>
```

**[Forker Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clr-wizard-3ncgya?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Awesome @Yurzui. Thanks